# How can i delete the space that created after UITableView section header removing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic, sections

I have an UITableView. It's dynamic table. When you touched the "Add File" button, i'm creating a new section and row. if you touch again, i'm creating only row. and when you touched the "Add Number" button, i'm creating a new section and row. if you touch again, i'm creating only row. This is OK. But if you remove the first section, second section doesn't focus to the top. I am adding some screenshot and all of my code.

Please help me.

**This is my First Screen**

[image]

**I added one "File" and Two "Number"**

[image]

**And I removed the "File" but second section didn't go up.**

[image]

**Code :**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tblListe,btnCancel,btnEdit;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    FileArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NumberArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    int a=0;
    if (section==0) {
        if(FileArr.count>0)
            a=FileArr.count;
    } else {
        if(NumberArr.count>0)
            a=NumberArr.count;
    }
    return a;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 37.0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *hucre = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    if(indexPath.section==0){
        hucre.textLabel.text=[FileArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else{
        hucre.textLabel.text=[NumberArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    hucre.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return hucre;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *AnaView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,0)];

    UIView *AsilView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,0,self.view.frame.size.width ,35)];

    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(5, 0, self.view.frame.size.width/3, 35);
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    int say=0;
    if(section==0){
        myLabel.text = @"Files";
        say=FileArr.count;
    }else{
        myLabel.text = @"Numbers";
        say=NumberArr.count;
    }
    myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    myLabel.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    myLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"ce1b27"];

    UIView *LineView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,AsilView.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width-5,2)];
    LineView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"ce1b27"];

    [AnaView addSubview:AsilView];
    [AnaView addSubview:myLabel];
    [AnaView addSubview:LineView];
    if (say>0) {
        return AnaView;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSString *x;
    if (section==0) {
        if(FileArr.count>0)
            x=@"Files";
        else
            x=nil;
    } else {
        if (NumberArr.count>0)
            x=@"Numbers";
        else
            x=nil;
    }
    return x;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return @"Delete";
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
        if (indexPath.section==0) {
            [FileArr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }else{
            [NumberArr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
    [self SatirIslem:0];
    //NSLog(@"%@",FileArr);
    [tblListe reloadData];
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)Duzenle:(id)sender {
    [tblListe setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    btnCancel.enabled = YES;
}

- (IBAction)Iptal:(id)sender {
    [tblListe setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    btnCancel.enabled = NO;
}

- (IBAction)DosyaEkle:(id)sender {
    [FileArr addObject:@"This is a File"];
    [self SatirIslem:1];
}
- (IBAction)NumaraEkle:(id)sender {
    [NumberArr addObject:@"This is a Number"];
    [self SatirIslem:1];
}

-(void)SatirIslem:(NSInteger) islem{
    CGFloat x=0,y=0,w=0,h=0;
    if (islem==1) { // satır Ekle
        x=tblListe.frame.origin.x;
        y=tblListe.frame.origin.y;
        w=tblListe.frame.size.width;
        h=tblListe.frame.size.height;
        if(FileArr.count==1 || NumberArr.count==1){
            h+=35+44; // 35 header için 44 satır için
        }else{
            h+=44;
        }

    }

    if (islem==0) {
        x=tblListe.frame.origin.x;
        y=tblListe.frame.origin.y;
        w=tblListe.frame.size.width;
        h=tblListe.contentSize.height;
        if(FileArr.count==0 && NumberArr.count==0){
            h=1;
        }else if(FileArr.count==0 || NumberArr.count==0) {
            h-=44+35;// 35 header için 44 satır için
        }else{
            h-=44;
        }
    }
    tblListe.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
    [tblListe reloadData];
}

-(UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hex
{
    NSString *cString = [[hex stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];

    if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor grayColor];
    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];    
    if ([cString length] != 6) return  [UIColor grayColor];    
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 2;
    NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];    
    range.location = 2;
    NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];    
    range.location = 4;
    NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];    
    unsigned int r, g, b;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];   
    return 
    [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)green:((float) g / 255.0f)                         blue:((float) b / 255.0f)alpha:1.0f];
}

@end
```

Comment: For future reference modifying the size of your screen shots will make your questions much more user friends, currently it is difficult to understand the question as the images are too big for the screen

Comment: You're right. Thanks for your advice. i edited my question.  and still waiting for solutions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried the code in your answers. when i add a new file it's shown like that, @Ashraf Tawfeeq , @Ian MacDonald

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by returning a different value for the height.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  if (section==0) {
    if(FileArr.count==0)
      return 0;
  } else {
    if(NumberArr.count==0)
      return 0;
  }
  return 37.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code resolve your problem.

```
  -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:NSInteger)section{
    if(FileArr.count==0 && NumberArr.count>0){
        if (section==0) {
            return 0.0;
        } else {
            return 37.0;
        }
    }else{
        return 37.0
    }
}
```